# Преобразовать строку в дату Python

Tags: python

Как преобразовать данные из JSON объекта в дату в Python?

Я получаю из JSON объекта дату `2020-06-10T08:00:06.476115+02:00`. Как мне преобразовать ее в `10.06.2020 08:00:06`?

Comment: так что вы туда загружали?

Answer (score 1):

Ваше время в формате [`ISO 8601`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), поэтому для парсинга можете воспользоваться [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = '2020-06-10T08:00:06.476115+02:00'
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s)
print(dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

***stdout:***

```py
10.06.2020 08:00:06
```

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо. Еще столкнулся с одной проблемой что иногда ругается на некорректную строку ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2020-06-10T09:14:00.55977+02:00' ,  как данную проблему можно исправить?

Comment: @ИгорьИонов А откуда у Вас эта строка? `Python` считает её невалидной, потому что для миллисекунд используется 5 цифр (а должно 3 или 6). Например, так сработает: `2020-06-10T09:14:00.559770+02:00`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Все данные беру через api, и когда парсю  json вижу что такие даты прилетают.